# Change default view of controller using view-list member: How to set view models?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm building a Joomla 2.5 component, and I want to change the view being rendered after a 'save' item action. This is easy enough (in the JControllerAdmin extended class constructor)

```
$this->view_list = "myview"
```

However, `myview` needs to load a couple of models to work. Elsewhere in the code this is done by a controller, for example  `controller.php` (the component's master controller in the component root):

```
$view = &$this->getView('myview', 'html');
$view->setModel($this->getModel('myviewSpecialModel'),false);
$view->display();
```

My question: I'm not sure where in `JControllerAdmin` I can put this code so the necessary models are loaded before the view is displayed. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions right, you have a controller that extends the JControllerAdmin.

So the **code you mentioned earlier should be inside the display() method** in the controller's class.

Does this answer your question?

Also also helpful might be the Joomla! Documentation: [Using multiple models in an MVC component](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_multiple_models_in_an_MVC_component)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Valentin, but JControllerAdmin doesn't support the display method (http://docs.joomla.org/JControllerAdmin/1.6)

Comment: Yes, my bad, JControllerAdmin does not implement the display() method. I don't quite understand why do you use JControllerAdmin. For example I would use JControllerForm where you can implement the edit() method and put your models there.

Comment: Because JControllerAdmin features the delete() method for removing items without requiring an associated form. Half of what I want to do is achieved in setting the view_list. It's just unfortunate that the view I specify here requires additional initalisation beyond loading the 'default' model for that view.